# When are Mosca pubsubCollection documents removed?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mosca

I need to store the data sent by devices in a collection. However, I dont want it in the format used by the `pubsubCollection`. So I decided to store it using `server.on('published')`.

So when are the documents from `pubsubCollection` removed by mosca? I dont want redundant data.

**PS:** I know I couldn't put this question properly, if you down vote, do tell me why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The collection is a capped collection in mongodb (see https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/), and the packets will be automatically removed by MongoDB when they reach the maximum size or disk or the maximum amount of packets. Both these values are tweakable.

Comment: Will it affect working of MQTT / mosca if the capping is less (not extremely less, but less)? I'm just learning MQTT